# x/c == 7 или x%7 == 0

Tags: java

Я понимаю, что вопрос банально прост, но, не бывает глупых вопросов)

```
int c, x//Любое число от 10 до 100
c=1;
if(x/c == 7){
syso("good');
c++;
}
```

Первый вариант забраковали и предпочли второй, вопрос почему? Якобы второй более точен

Спасибо за ответ
Это первый мой вопрос, возможно что- то не учел, но я не понимаю в чем размытость? Код я написал, если там int, знаяит там int и ничто другое первый мой вариант при делении получать 7, второй чтоб остаток был равен 0, по мне в случае int это два равноценных ответа. Не принял его препод. Написав, что второй его вариант более точен

Не думал, что будет всё так сложно...
Ок, ещё раз.
Задача-игра: 1)цель выбрать число х от 10 до 100
И напечатать от 1 до х последовательность, если встречаем число 7 или его множитель, будет напечатана например, слово "seven"
Пример принта:
x=22
1,2,3,4,5,6,seven,8,9,10,11,12,13,seven,15,16,17,18,19,20,seven,22
Вопрос я задал несколько раз. Почему условиe
if (x/c == 7) не приняли, написав, что (х%7 == 0) более точное 
Переменные все int

Comment: Что у вас за задача?

Comment: Скорее всего, вам хотели указать на тот факт, что **целочисленное деление отбрасывает дробную часть**. Но либо способ какой-то бредовый, либо вы описали не все обстоятельства.

Comment: @Александр а она-то здесь при чём? В Python такая проблема тоже существует, а там типизация динамическая.

Comment: @D-side я имел ввиду то,что Вы написали Выше,поскольку напиши я деление в консоли браузера получил бы дробное число

Comment: Что-то типа игры, ввести число х (от 10 до 100 )
Начинается цикл от 1 до числа х. Печатаем кажое число...Когда встречаем 7 , 2×7, 3×7  вместо числа печатаем "good" нaпример

Comment: @Biohazard любое число,наверное x был типа double?

Comment: Нет ребят int всё int

Comment: Из-за простоты вопроса, я что-то не стал сильно заморачиваться и написал первое, что пришло в голову...
Работа с modulo было много и я в принципе люблю его использовать, но мне непонятно почему мой вариант забраковали , т.б работа только с int..

Comment: Нужно ясно указать в вопросе (с помощью кнопки «править») задачу, оба варианта, и по каким причинам один из вариантов не принят (кем?). Сейчас вопрос слишком размытый.

Comment: Потому, что при делении целого на целое отбрасывается дробная часть. Т.е. 71/10==7, 72/10==7. 79/10==7 и т.д.

Comment: rjhdby, в этом есть логика и это является аргументом,  но почему тогда (15/2 == 7) не срабатывает? А точнее код работает в соотвествии с задачей...?

Answer (score 0):

Если делить на 1, то результатом деления станет само число. Соответственно, ни на какие множители `x / 1 == 7` не проверяет - только на равенство 7. А вариант `x % 7 == 0` проверяет на все числа, кратные 7.

После увеличения `c` получается проблема с целочисленным делением. Даже при значении `2` получается возможная ошибка: `14 / 2 == 7` и `15 / 2 == 7`. Очевидно, что true во втором случае не является желаемым.

Comment: Но я же указал с++; ....... я уже не знаю куда что написать добавить....задача/вопрос разжевана по-максимуму

Comment: При чём тут вообще язык??

Comment: c переменная....с++ код сверху ....
Я имею ввиду c++ c-- ++c и т.д))

Comment: а, понял. но цикла в коде нет. тогда как тебе в комментариях сказали - оно округляется.

Comment: дополнил ответ.